# Updating the state of data in the client in response to the work of other clients

Tags: django, angularjs

So I have an application that could theoretically be used by multiple people at the same time, filling positions in a list of lists.  The client app is in angular and is using a grid to display the lists of lists, the backend is in Django.

I'm having a hard time coming up with a way to signal client A, that client B did something.  Multi-threading would let me do some long polling with locks and signals, but multi-processing makes this much more difficult.

How do I keep both (could be more than 2) of the clients up to date with the state/content of the list of lists as it is on the server?

Right now I'm restricting the number of users to 1, but this is not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the clients pull changes from the server every X seconds, then the server can respond with changes list or with no change. This is not real realtime but if you make the pull delta low it will look like almost real time.
Alterantively, you can use websockets, but AFAIK, this is not supported by django, so you need to manage the websockets using tornado python or node.js or something like.

I would suggest using redis or other memory based datastore to communicate and propagate teh changes between the different servers.

Comment: If I used redis, wouldn't I have a port issue on the website (ports not matching)?  And is redis even suited for that kind of thing where authentication is important?  I know memcached wouldn't be suitable.

Comment: let's say you put 2 servers, one django and one torndao. They will communicate through redis (using pub/sub or just pulling). The client will make all HTTP connections with the django server, and will open websocket connection to the tornado. Redis is only in the backend, and the webclient is not exposed to it.